# Manually moving an ssh key

Tags: linux, ssh

I have had to re-install my operating system (linux). I saved the home directory including the `.ssh` folder with private and public keys.

I wish to manually bring that over to the new system as I use to access a number of git repos and servers.

How do I do this?

I tried simply copying the folder over with the key inside (I only had a single ssh key pair) but when I try to do a git clone it says permission denied.

Is there some other step needed to make the key work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your user ID on the old system is different to the new system. Try "chown username ~/.ssh/*"

You should also ensure your private key is only readable by you - "chmod 500 ~/.ssh/id_rsa"

Comment: It was this. somewhere in the copy the owner got changed to root. I had to ```chown -R username: ~/.ssh```